# error "expected ')' before '&' token" when calling a function with pointers

Tags: c

I am getting the error `expected ')' before '&' token` on this line:
`&p1, &p2, &q1, &q2);`, which is part of the `void calcula_pq (...)` function.

I can't figure out how to fix it. Please, help me.

This is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
void calcula_pq ( double xi, double yi, double div, double xk, double yk, 
double dkv, double x2, double y2, double d2v, double x3, double y3, 
double d3v, double *p1, double *p2, double *q1, double *q2);


int main ()
{
    double p1, p2, q1, q2, xi, yi, div, xj, yj, djv, xk, yk, dkv;
    scanf ("%lf%lf%lf%lf%lf%lf%lf%lf%lf", &xi, &yi, &div, &xj, &yj, &djv, 
    &xk, &yk, &dkv);
    void calcula_pq ( xi, yi, div, xk, yk, dkv, xk, yk, dkv, xj, yj, djv, 
                      &p1, &p2, &q1, &q2);
    printf ("%.10f   %.10f    %.10f   %.10f", p1, p2, q1, q2);
    return 0;
}



void calcula_pq ( double xi, double yi, double div, double xk, double yk, 
double dkv, double x2, double y2, double d2v, double x3, double y3, 
double d3v, double *p1, double *p2, double *q1, double *q2){

    double pa, pb, qa, qb;

    pa = ( ( (xi*xi) - (x2*x2) + (yi*yi) - (y2*y2) - (div*div) + (d2v*d2v) / 
         (2 * (xi - x2) ) );
    pb = ( ( (x3*x3) - (xk*xk) + (y3*y3) - (yk*yk) - (d3v*d3v) + (dkv*dkv) / 
         (2 * (x3 - xk) ) );
    qa = ( (y2 - yi) / (xi - x2));
    qb = ( (yk - y3) / (x3 - xk));
    *p1 = pa;
    *p2 = pb;
    *q1 = qa;
    *q2 = qb;
}
```

Comment: Whats the `void` doing at the call?

Comment: The `void` makes it look like a declaration, and you can't put `&p1` in a declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method call inside the main having void.. remove that and try

change from

```
void calcula_pq ( xi, yi, div, xk, yk, dkv, xk, yk, dkv, xj, yj, djv, 
                      &p1, &p2, &q1, &q2);
```

to

```
calcula_pq ( xi, yi, div, xk, yk, dkv, xk, yk, dkv, xj, yj, djv, 
                          &p1, &p2, &q1, &q2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `void` before `calcula_pq (...` or enclose it in parenthesis if you intended to cast there. But I assume you did copy and paste the signature and missed that.

Two closing parenthesis were also missing (in `calcula_pq` here `(2 * (xi - x2) ) );` and here `(2 * (x3 - xk) ) );`).

```
#include <stdio.h>
void calcula_pq ( double xi, double yi, double div, double xk, double yk, 
double dkv, double x2, double y2, double d2v, double x3, double y3, 
double d3v, double *p1, double *p2, double *q1, double *q2);


int main ()
{
    double p1, p2, q1, q2, xi, yi, div, xj, yj, djv, xk, yk, dkv;
    scanf ("%lf%lf%lf%lf%lf%lf%lf%lf%lf", &xi, &yi, &div, &xj, &yj, &djv, 
    &xk, &yk, &dkv);
    calcula_pq ( xi, yi, div, xk, yk, dkv, xk, yk, dkv, xj, yj, djv, // remove void
                      &p1, &p2, &q1, &q2);
    printf ("%.10f   %.10f    %.10f   %.10f", p1, p2, q1, q2);
    return 0;
}



void calcula_pq ( double xi, double yi, double div, double xk, double yk, 
double dkv, double x2, double y2, double d2v, double x3, double y3, 
double d3v, double *p1, double *p2, double *q1, double *q2){

    double pa, pb, qa, qb;

    pa = ( ( (xi*xi) - (x2*x2) + (yi*yi) - (y2*y2) - (div*div) + (d2v*d2v) / 
         (2 * (xi - x2) ) ) ); // add )
    pb = ( ( (x3*x3) - (xk*xk) + (y3*y3) - (yk*yk) - (d3v*d3v) + (dkv*dkv) / 
         (2 * (x3 - xk) ) ) ); // add )
    qa = ( (y2 - yi) / (xi - x2));
    qb = ( (yk - y3) / (x3 - xk));
    *p1 = pa;
    *p2 = pb;
    *q1 = qa;
    *q2 = qb;
}
```